# Is the $\ell$-Diffie Hellman Inversion easy when g is known?

Tags: diffie-hellman

From [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121224072406/https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/wiki/index.php/Discrete_Logarithms) they define the $\ell$-Diffie Hellman inversion problem as:

> Given $g^{a},g^{a^2}\ldots,g^{a^{\ell}} \in G$, compute $g^{a^{-1}}$

Would this problem become easy if the generator $g$ is also known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

The stated $l$-DHI problem is believed to remain hard when $g$ is known.

Actually, in the [quoted page](https://web.archive.org/web/20121224072406/https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/wiki/index.php/Discrete_Logarithms), it is assumed that $g$ is known throughout. This is obvious in particular in the sections on DLP and CDH.

Comment: I missed that bit at the top of the page. I got confused because some of the other assumptions list g to be explicitly known.

Comment: @blz: You did _not_ miss that bit - it was missing, I added it.

Answer (score 3):

No. The generator $g$ is a public parameter of the group $G$. You cannot perform a Diffie-Hellman handshake unless both parties agree on the generator (as well as any other parameter that defines $G$), so naturally any variation of the Diffie-Hellman problem must, by definition, assume the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know about the paper [Variations of Diffie-Hellman Problem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.3007) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.3007&rep=rep1&type=pdf))? The problem you stated is the generalization of the inversion problem stated in that paper. You can use their technique to prove the relation.

Comment: I fail to locate the paper.